# Flutter Container Match Parent inside Column

Tags: flutter, layout, containers

I am quite a newbie in Flutter.

I tried several pieces of stuff but I failed at the end. 
I have a row and this row contains two different columns.

My question is I am trying to add `Container` which matches the parent until other columns height into the first column.

I already tried widgets like `Flex`, `Expanded` etc. And I got infinity error. Since the first column has no idea about other columns size.

[image]

```dart
Widget _buildProgressVideoCall() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
                child: Image.asset(
                  ImageAssets.videocall,
                  scale: 3.0,
                ),
                radius: 22,
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Expanded(child: Container(
                child: Image.asset(
                  ImageAssets.progressDots,
                  repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
                )))
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[ // Fixed Height Widgets Buttons etc.
 ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you post you code just so im sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I added code thanks @wcyankees424

Answer (score 0):

If I have your setup right try doing this I might not have it quite right let me know if I misunderstand what you want.

```
Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
```